# making relation from one sql table with neo4j spring data

Tags: java, spring, graph, neo4j

I have table with following columns

from 
to
cc
subject
date_sent

I want to convert it to neo4j and make relations , for example

from -> to
to >from
I do not know about cc, keep it as the node or?

Also I do not know, what is the better keep subject and date in the relation entity or node entity?

what kind of structure I need really?
in which way better make relations between users?

Any suggestions?

I find advice how to right convert mailbox to neo4j relations and nodes. Any body done similar job?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Really not sure if this use case is the best fit for a graph representation, but if at all you want to do that,  one approach would be -

[image]

*Users* are nodes. *Mail* is node with properties *subject* and *date sent*. *From*, *To* and *cc* as relationships

Comment: Actually i done in this way, but I lost CC and can not understand how to fetch or join subject/body/sent_date

Comment: I added screens of my entities, but I think it is not fully clear and not good relations:(

Comment: Also user can send not one mail to the another user, nodes must be unique , but with a lot of similar relations....The main goal when get a user receiver also get full email with it:(

Comment: check out the graph-databases book by Ian Robinson and Jim Webber, it has a good email example (free ebook: http://graphdatabases.com)